# AngularJS, $scope.amount is not showing to two decimals when a on double click event is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, decimal

I have two `$scope` object. `$scope.grandTotal` and `$scope.amount`, if i double click on the input field for `$scope.amount`, it automatically populates the input with the value from `$scope.grandTotal`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" ng-model="tenderedAmount" ng-change="updateBalance();" ng-dblclick="autoFill()" class="form-control" awnum num-sep="." num-int="15" num-thousand="true">
```

the above is the input code and where the double click event is.

```
$scope.autoFill = function(){
    $scope.tenderedAmount = $scope.grandTotal;
    $scope.updateBalance();
};
```

the above is the function autofill, which is called during the doubleclick event.
Now here's my issue, say `$scope.grandTotal` is 1400.10, when i doubleclick the input for `$scope.amount`, it fills as 1400.1, how do i make it where it fills it as 1400.10 ? 
I have tried using `Math.round` and `toFix(2)`, but both dont work..

Comment: Can you make a  js Fiddle for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, inject `$filter` and use the `number` filter as follows:

```
testModule.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
 ....

 $scope.autoFill = function(){
    var grandTotal = $scope.grandTotal;
    $scope.tenderedAmount = $filter('number')(grandTotal, 2)
    $scope.updateBalance();
 };

 ....

}]);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hey there! thanks for the quick response, it still doesn't work :/..
the thing is there are two input's, one is disabled and one is a text input(has to be text, due to various reasons), the disabled input is the $scope.grandTotal, and the other is $scope.tenderedAmount, the tenderedAmount input enables you to enter things in it. so when i use a double click mouse event on it, it fills up the tenderedamount based on the grandTotal automatically. however in my case, if its a .10, the 0 is always missing, so it returns .1

Comment: hey, so are you getting any error after injecting $filter? Or it is still showing the same thing without any errors?

Comment: no error is given when i use $filter, but it's still returning xxx.1 not xxx.10

Comment: did you try using `console.log($scope.tenderedAmount)` to see the value?

Comment: yes, in the console.log, it shows xxx.10, but in the input box, it is xxx.1 the 0 at the back is not there.

Comment: can you try using number field instead of text field? 
`<input id="tenderd_amount" type="number" step="0.01"/>`

Comment: i cant use input type="text" due to using a library called awnum, so that when i type it automatically records 1000 as 1,000. lol

Comment: can you edit the question by adding some details about your template file?

Answer (score 0):

`Number(123).toFixed(2)` returns 123.00.

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$scope.tenderedAmount = (Math.round($scope.grandTotal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

And make sure input type is number not text.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
parseFloat(Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var num1 = parseFloat(Math.round(100.1 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        var num2 = parseFloat(Math.round(1000.1456 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
        console.log(num1);
        console.log(num2);
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

The Angular Number filter.

```
$scope.tenderedAmount = $filter('number')($scope.grandTotal, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
$scope.tenderedAmount = $scope.grandTotal.toFixed(2);

garndTotal value should be a number.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.grandTotal = 123.123;
  $scope.tenderedAmount = 123.123;
  $scope.autoFill = function(){
                $scope.tenderedAmount = $scope.grandTotal.toFixed(2);
            };    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular filter is the best way:

```
$scope.tenderedAmount = $filter('number')(grandTotal, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply use :**

```
$filter('number')($scope.grandTotal, 2)
```

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.autoFill = function(){
        $scope.grandTotal = 1400.10;
        $scope.tenderedAmount = $filter('number')($scope.grandTotal,2);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" ng-model="tenderedAmount" ng-dblclick="autoFill()" class="form-control" awnum num-sep="." num-int="15" num-thousand="true">
</div>
```

## -----OR-----

```
{{ tenderedAmount | number:2 }}
```